# Appcelerator Studio can't login

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to use Appcelerator Studio but when it starts I can't write my e-mail on the textbox.

**UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I am on Linux Ubuntu 16.04**

I can press buttons or click link but **I can't insert any text** on the "Email" or "Password" field, it seems like they are disabled or there is a bug which doesn't put focus on them even if I click:

[image]

This is the console stack trace:

```
➜  Appcelerator_Studio ./AppceleratorStudio 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
(Build 4.8.1.1480393991) [ERROR]  null
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:395)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:381)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:345)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processResult(ProcessRunner.java:432)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeAppcCLI.runCommand(NodeAppcCLI.java:238)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.verifyAppcWhoami(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1236)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.access$4(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1233)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$3.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:321)
(Build 4.8.1.1480393991) [ERROR]  Failed to check login status. Likely not logged in.
```

Comment: have you tried logging in on CLI? Use `appc login`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bug might be specific to your OS environment.

However, try login from CLI and then launch the studio.That will skip login screen.

```
appc login
```

And, looking at the console log - it's better to use JDK 1.7 as JDK 1.8 and higher is not officially supported by Appcelerator Studio 4.8.1.

Comment: Use oracle JDK.